# Iphone Application with Symfony 1.4

Tags: iphone, ios, symfony1

I'm building a simple iPhone app that synchronizes to a webservice served by Symfony 1.4. This app requires the user to be logged in.

My question is, how can the user log in Symfony from the iPhone app? And how can I keep the session opened through the next petitions? Is this secure?

Chapter 15 of the Practical Symfony book talks about webservices, but I can't find any guide about sessions.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How did you ned up accomplishing this? Im in the same situation now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SOAP web service also. But this is little complex. You can send the file attached to XForm and Post to the service

Detailed implementation of SOAP in PHP

http://www.vankouteren.eu/blog/2009/03/simple-php-soap-example/

Answer (score 0):

You can build a rest service for symfony modules. You can get login through REST service.

Your example service will be like this

www.example.com?username=user&password=pass

Comment: How to send a file through restfull service and how to parse it.